# Cassandra data modeling for range queries using timestamp

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling, cql

I need to create a table with 4 columns:

- timestamp BIGINT
- name VARCHAR
- value VARCHAR
- value2 VARCHAR

I have 3 required queries:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE timestamp > xxx
AND timestamp < xxx;

SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE name = 'xxx';

SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE name = 'xxx'
AND timestamp > xxx
AND timestamp < xxx;
```

The result needs to be sorted by timestamp.
When I use:

```
CREATE TABLE table (
    timestamp BIGINT,
    name VARCHAR,
    value VARCHAR,
    value2 VARCHAR,
    PRIMARY KEY (timestamp)
);
```

the result is never sorted.
When I use:

```
CREATE TABLE table (
    timestamp BIGINT,
    name VARCHAR,
    value VARCHAR,
    value2 VARCHAR,
    PRIMARY KEY (name, timestamp)
);
```

the result is sorted by name > timestamp which is wrong.

```
name | timestamp
------------------------
   a | 20170804142825729
   a | 20170804142655569
   a | 20170804142650546
   a | 20170804142645516
   a | 20170804142640515
   a | 20170804142620454
   b | 20170804143446311
   b | 20170804143431287
   b | 20170804143421277
   b | 20170804142920802
   b | 20170804142910787
```

How do I do this using Cassandra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cassandra order data by clustering key group by partition key**

In your case first table have only partition key `timestamp`, no clustering key. So data will not be sorted.

And For the second table partition key is `name` and clustering key is `timestamp`. So your data will sorted by `timestamp` group by `name`. Means data will be first group by it's `name` then each group will be sorted separately by `timestamp`.

**Edited**

So you need to add a partition key like below :

```
CREATE TABLE table (
    year BIGINT,
    month BIGINT,
    timestamp BIGINT,
    name VARCHAR,
    value VARCHAR,
    value2 VARCHAR,
    PRIMARY KEY ((year, month), timestamp)
);
```

here `(year, month)` is the composite partition key. You have to insert the year and month from the timestamp. So your data will be sorted by `timestamp` within a year and month

Comment: I know this. Like I said, I need to sort by `timestamp` only. I don't wanna use dummy columns, but I can't believe I have to sort on the client-side, because this will simply don't work anymore if the data amount is getting huge. Is there no way using a cassandra database solving my problem?

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I need. I'd like to understand this... I read the article We Shall Have Order (https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/we-shall-have-order). They do the same to avoid reaching the row-groth of 2 billion columns per partition. In my case, I'd call it a dummy column for partitioning and sorting. It's solving my problem because the composite key is like a incrementing number. But won't this produce a hot spot on partitioning?

Comment: Just curious, how will this table solve your select queries involving name=??

Comment: Have to maintain two table this one and the question's 2nd table

Comment: I tried the statements and both work with the "new" table layout?